# Reading time from Excel file in VB.NET returns an integer

Tags: vb.net, datetime-format

I was trying to read an Excel file to a VB.NET application. When reading the Excel file, the column time in the file does not return a time format, rather it returns an integer, e.g.:

```
17:14:04 --> 0.718101852
13:26:12 --> 0.559861111
7:26:29  --> 0.31005787
```

How can I turn these numbers back to time format?

Please Help me thanks

Comment: How your code for reading the excel file exactly?

Comment: TextBox1.Text = worksheet.Cells(2, 3).Value I used the Microsoft Excel Library .. Actually .. that integer number came from the excel file itself but it displays the integer number in a time format.. how weird XD now Im wondering how to convert that integer to time format ..

Comment: I edited my answers, its modified from Eldar answers. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = (New DateTime()).AddDays(0.559861111)
```

It is working for me. It returns:

```
13:26:12 from 0.559861111
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim dttm As DateTime = (New DateTime()).AddDays(worksheet.Cells(2, 3))
TextBox1.Text = ddtm.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

My excel worksheet is like this:

[image: Sample Excel sheet, contain Date and Time]

And my code is like this, It is works well.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook

Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim DateVal As String, TimeVal As Double, myTime as Date

On Error GoTo OpenCSVfileError

xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet

Dim xRng As Excel.Range

xRng = CType(xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 1), Excel.Range)
DateVal = xRng.Value.ToString
myTime = CDate(DateVal)
xRng = CType(xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2), Excel.Range)
TimeVal = CDbl(xRng.Value.ToString)
myTime = myTime.AddDays(TimeVal)
OpenCSVfileError:
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
```